# Menu is not showing pdf file- pdf Annotation in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, ibooks, pdf-annotations

I am developing the app like ibooks by [reference](https://github.com/vfr/Reader),in that the pdf is not enabling the menu i.e while I long tap the pdf it not showing Menu like **copy , define**.

How can I work in menu? Help me.

Answer (score 0):

The linked solution simply does not implement text selection or glyph coordinate extraction/conversion. You need to parse the PDF page content stream and track glyphs on the page. `CGPDFOperatorTable` can be a starting point, however I suggest reading the PDF spec and getting familiar with the multiple transformation matrix states that a page can have - it's quite tricky to get right. You also need to [embed various CMaps](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/cmap/wiki/Home/) (character maps) so that all fonts can be correctly parsed. It took me more than a year to get a reliable text extraction for >99% of all PDF documents. If you want to save this time, you can check out the commercial PDF SDK I am working - google for PSPDFKit. We support iOS and Android.